# php insert to mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have an issue inserting data to table in php,the problem I am facing maybe it is not difficult to solve but Im new in php development and could not solve it, here is my code

```html
  <table class="table-fill">

<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
<td class="text-left"><input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "name"></td>
<td class="text-left">name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"><input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "Quantity" id="QTY"></td>
<td class="text-left">QTY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"><input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
                             name = "Type" id="type"></td>
<td class="text-left">type</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"><input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "price" id="prs"></td>
<td class="text-left">price</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td class="text-left"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></td>
<td class="text-left">image</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text-left">  <input type="submit" value="Submit1" name="Submit1"></td>
<td class="text-left">Register</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
                        

 </div>
        <div id="footer">
  <div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
         <?php
 
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   
    
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   
   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
  
   if (isset($_post('Submit1')))
   {
   $name=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name');
   $QTY=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Quantity');
   $type=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Type');
   $sql = "INSERT INTO products (ProductName, Quantity,Price)
    VALUES ('$name','$QTY','$type')";


//('$_POST['name']','$_POST['Quantity']','$_POST['Type']')";      
   mysql_select_db('pharmacynew');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
   
   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   
   echo "Entered data successfully\n";
   
   mysql_close($conn);
}       // put your code here
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

the problem Iam facing when I run the page ,it shows me this error 
"Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) "
Can any body tell me why is this problem appearing and how to overcome it,
many thanks

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated, please use `mysqli` in future development.

Comment: I will do cheers

Comment: I for one, don't see form tags.

Comment: Good catch, Fred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (isset($_post('Submit1')))
```

By using regular brackets `(` and `)` you're trying to use `$_post` as a function instead of a variable. That's not allowed within `isset()`.

You need to use angled brackets `[` and `]` to read values from the `$_post` array (which should be `$_POST` in uppercase, by the way).

Simply change that line to

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit1"]))
```

Comment: I have modified the code to what you said and the problem has gone but the data has not been inserted

Comment: Well, that's a different issue. If you echo the contents of `$sql`, does the query match what you expect? Do you get an error if you execute that query manually, say via the `mysql` commandline or via a tool like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: still not adding

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: execute the query manually it works fine  1 row inserted. [br] Inserted row id: 10 (Query took 0.2410 seconds.)
INSERT INTO products (ProductName, Quantity,Price) VALUES ('fff','4','3')

Comment: No I dont get error message but no thing happening when i click the button

Comment: Like Fred said, the input fields are not in a `<form>` tag. The code inside the `if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) { ... }` is probably not being executed without one. Try that.

Comment: ... and a post method. `<form>` defaults to GET if "post" isn't implied.

Comment: Here we go ,now it working fine I thank you all

Comment: in all fairness and for future visitors, the answer should contain the full solution and not rely on comments given.

Comment: I agree, but in this case the original question was "why am I getting a fatal error and how do I fix it". That is answered in the answer. These comments answer the follow-up question of "how do I fix all the other things wrong with this script", which IMO is unrelated to the original question.